# How to change data using functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference between these examples and why are the outputs like this?
Why do we write `print A` or `print L`?

```
def f(N):
    N = N+20

def g():
    A =10
    print A
    f(A)
    print a

#  output 
#  10
#  10

def f(List):
    List[0] = 'A'

def g():
    L = [1,2,3]
    print L 
    f(L)
    print L

#  output 
#  [1,2,3]
#  ['A',2,3]
```

Comment: Please indent your code. There are no return statements in your functions?

Comment: The first example simply sets a new local variable `N` equal to 30 (`N + 20`), which is simply thrown away. The second one alters the mutable list it is passed. (And note that integers, and strings too, are immutable.)

Comment: read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

First you have written function `f` with one argument

```
def f(N):
    N = N+20
```

Second function `g` with no arguments, with local variable `A=10`

```
def g():
   A =10
   print A  #so prints 10
   f(A)      # call function `f` passing `10 f(10)` but not printing anything and, not holding return value
   print a   # print `a` values but in the post you have not shown where you declared this `a`
```

Third function `f` with one argument, and replacing `0` index of value (overrides above function `f`)

```
def f(List):
       List[0] = 'A'
```

Fourth function `g` with local variable `L` of type `List` (overrides above function `g`)

```
def g():
   L = [1,2,3]
   print L  # print list L
   f(L)    # called function `f` passing list so replaces `0` index of `L`
   print L  # prints modified `L`
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you pass a number to `f()` it will receive a copy of the number.

But when you pass a list to `f()` it will receive a reference to that.

Take a look at [Difference between call by value and call by reference](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-call-by-reference-and-call-by-value)

Comment: absolutely incorrect. The evaluation strategy does *not change based on the type of object being passed*

Comment: It was just an example not a complete answer. Because there are too many answers to this question and I mentioned one :)

Comment: It is not correct at all. Again, *the evaluation strategy does not change depending on the type of the object*. numbers and lists get passed in exactly the same way